# How to share states between different component while none of them are connected to each other by any parent child relation?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I find it interesting. I have a button and clicking on that button will set some state inside that class as true and based on that the title of the button will change.
I want to change some other React component in some other class based on this state change. How can I do that ?

For example :

```
var Comp1 = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { logged_in: false }
    },

    handleClick: function() {
        this.setState({logged_in: !this.state.logged_in});
    },

    render: function() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                   {this.state.logged_in ? "SIGN OUT" : "SIGN IN"} 
               </button>;
    }

})
```

Here is my second component which is rendered separately.

```
var Comp2 = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <div>
                   {Comp1.state.logged_in ? "You are in" : "You need a login"}
               </div>;
    }
})
```

This is one component. I want to use the state of this component in another component either by passing the stat (though I am not using both the component in composite format, so they are independent by nature) or based on change in the state I can define another sate in the second component.

Comment: React has no concept of inter component communication - You would have to resort to a move to a Flux-like based architecture for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a shared object that can handle the state that these two objects represent. It is going to be easier to pick a standard model for doing this, like [redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux) or [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), than to come up with your own. Learning one of these patterns is crucial to development in React. I personally recommend redux.

**This is a *very* stripped down version of what Flux would look like.** It is not intended to be a real solution, just to provide a glimpse of the pattern. If you just want to skip to the code, here is [a codepen](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/QjRVqJ?editors=001).

The shared object is typically referred to as a **store**. Stores hold state, and provide methods to subscribe to changes in that state. Mutating this state would usually by done by calling publishing an event with **dispatcher** that notifies the store, but for simplicity I have included a publish function on the store itself

```
let loginStore = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  _subscribers: new Set(),
  subscribeToLogin(callback) {
    this._subscribers.add(callback);
  },
  unsubscribeToLogin(callback) {
    this._subscribers.delete(callback);
  },
  publishLogin(newState) {
    this.isLoggedIn = newState;
    this._subscribers.forEach(s => s(this.isLoggedIn));
  }
};
```

Once a pub/sub system is in place, the components will need to subcribe to it. The login button mutates this state, so it will also publish.

```
class LoginButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {isLoggedIn: loginStore.isLoggedIn};
  }
  update = (isLoggedIn) => {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn});
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    loginStore.subscribeToLogin(this.update);
  }
  componentDidUnmount(){
    loginStore.unsubscribeToLogin(this.update);
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    loginStore.publishLogin(!this.state.isLoggedIn);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isLoggedIn ? "SIGN OUT" : "SIGN IN"} 
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class LoginHeader extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {isLoggedIn: loginStore.isLoggedIn};
  }
  update = (isLoggedIn) => {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn});
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    loginStore.subscribeToLogin(this.update);
  }
  componentDidUnmount(){
    loginStore.unsubscribeToLogin(this.update);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.isLoggedIn ? "You are in" : "You need a login"}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

You'll notice the second component does not refer to the state of the first component, but the state of the store. As you mentioned, since they do not have a reference to each other, and do not have a common parent, they *cannot* depend directly on each other for the `loggedIn` state.